# Arduino-controlled bench power supply

Tags: power-supply, operational-amplifier, power, lm317, digital-potentiometer

I'm looking for a schematic to control an LM317 and an LM337 from an Arduino using [MCP42010](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/aemDocuments/documents/OTH/ProductDocuments/DataSheets/11195c.pdf) digital pots.
I'd like to build this schematic (input dual 30 V, 500 mA transformer per coil):

[image: this schematic]

I want to use digital pots instead, to control the voltage from a microcontroller. However, I must add an op-amp in order to use digital pots and I can do it only for the positive voltage.

[image]

For the negative voltage, I didn't find any schematic yet.
Could anyone post me a link to a schematic that lets me control an LM337 and an LM317 at once with digital pots or op-amps?

Comment: An opamp using V- as its -ve  supply and V+ as its +ve supply can accept inputs and provide outputs across most of the total supply range (limited by input common mode voltage.) Dpot Vout that is +ve wrt ground can be amplified - still positive and then either translated by a fixed amount to below ground (subtract a constant voltage) OR (better) invert and set relative to ground so for Vpot = 0 to +Vpmax wrt ground the opamp outputs 0 to -Vpmax below ground. This takes a single differential amplifier with unity gain. OR you can roll the gain stage and inverting amp into one.

Comment: @Russell McMahon - As I understand, you offer to set inverting opAmp for negative reference ping?
Would it be hard for you to paint schematic by hand or provide a link from in internet? I would appreciate it.
Thank you

Comment: I mentioned a differential amplifier BUT in this case Vpot and the required -ve output are both ground referenced so you get a very simple design. See eg [this example - gain and inversion](http://www.simplecircuitdiagram.com/2010/03/13/op-amp-application-inverting-amplifier/)

Comment: Another basic tutorial [here](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/opamp/opamp_2.html)

Comment: @Russell McMahon - Think I've got your point. I'll try on breadboard later on at home, and after I'll get results, will mark topic as answered. Thank you anyway. :)

Comment: Just curious. Do you intend having the two voltages track each other? In short, do you only want _one_ digital pot and to have both voltages have the same output value based on that? Or are these to be independently controlled?

Comment: @Jonk - Hi I think you're going to ask about tracking power supply. If you have any good schematic, please share. In this case, I'm villing to have Voltmeter and Ammeter (with shunt resistor), checked by microcontroller, so I can do tracking on a software level and do mirror / tracking adjustments from MC. Independent regulators will allow me to simulate rare situations. For example like yesterday +30 and -7. 
Thank you for asking :)

Comment: You might look here: https://hackaday.io/project/4154-bench-power-supply/log/16038-final-design-for-rev-10 as it's not too difficult to follow. Just keep in mind that his schematic shows a (+) regulator, but that the design can be _flipped_ to use the LM337 instead for a negative supply rail. There's some text there explaining that fact, but you do have to use your head as well.

Comment: If you're interested in a start to end video tutorial on basically this exact project, [EEVBlog Power Supply Design #1-8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CIGjActDeoM&list=PLBF35875F73B5C9B5) might be a good resource if you run into any "traps for young players."

Comment: Just so that you know, there is a much better way to do this which is to use an adjustable SMPS IC like LM2586. Although even the simplest designs are potentially difficult to get right as these are essentially high frequency power circuits which are sensitive.

Comment: If you want a cheap bench power supply that works, get Korad KA3003P/3005P. It has a USB port and you can control it with your PC. For the price, it's hard to beat with DIY...

Answer (score 1):

@Russell McMahon - Circuit with inverted opAmp worked. At the moment I can't do full test, but with voltage converter (+30 and -7, basically no load only oscilloscope test), values moves full range up and down. I need to set proper resistor values and use proper transformer. But I think it will work anyway. 
And I came to idea to use as reference source digital pots them-self. So simply replace opAmp outputs to digital pots. But this needs to be tested later on. If you'll get other useful links to related topic, please post those as well. 
Thank you. :)

[image]

Comment: Just comment about Digital potentiometers. They have limitation for 5V. So I can't use it as ADJ reference more than 5V. (tested yesterday)
This means, that I need use digital pot, gain it via opAmp up to 30V, and then apply to ADJ. 
for negative voltage I must use inverting gain and apply it to LM337.

Comment: LM358 running from 60V total supply? I spy Magic Smoke! You need something like LM344, and even then there's not much safety margin.

Comment: _Digital potentiometers [are limited to] 5V_ - not true; refer to the MCP41HVX1 for instance - https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/20005207B.pdf